# NSOperation never gets deallocated

Tags: ios, instruments, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have objects that extends NSOperation.
I also have NSOperationQueue.

I have a timer that NSLogs operationCount property of that NSOperationQueue every 0.5 seconds.

I add new operations to queue and after all of them are finished, queue logs 0 just as expected.

Problem is that Instruments reports that there are still living NSOperation objects living.

I hold no references to NSOperation, I only alloc-init them and add them to the queue.

The number of living NSOperation objects is 11 (???) in Instruments. If I add 5 new operations, NSLog logs 5... 4.... 3.... 2 .... 1... 0.
And instruments are behaving like: 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11 ...

Any clue on this?

I could KVO isFinished property and set to nil, but I am I wonder why are those objects still alive.

Comment: Retain cycle maybe? Are you using ARC?

Comment: ARC it is. And there is no retain cycle as far as I can tell.

Comment: Maybe Cocoa itself is using NSOperations. Have you tried looking at who exactly is retaining them?

Comment: Can I see this through Instruments?

Comment: Yup, I believe so. Use the "Allocations" instrument, check "Record Reference Counts" and run. You should see a list of all the classes in your app. Click on the class you want (`NSOperation` here), that should show a list of all the instances of that class. Then click on the instance you want, and bam, here is the list of each retain/release call. You should be able to determine which one is too much ;)

Comment: Just took a sample screenshot of what you should get : http://tinypic.com/r/28sycm9/6

Comment: Will try it tomorrow. I was profiling with memory leaks.

Comment: It looks like that was some kind of "anomaly" in Instruments since I can't reproduce this anymore. NSOperation objects are realeasing normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Instruments were causing this since this is not happening anymore and I didn't touch that code before this new tests.